# REST API to fetch data from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, salesforce-commerce-cloud

My site is in 2 different domains SFCC and Wordpress. Few pages and its contents are from Wordpress. When I search for any content which is present in WP it does not show for now.
I want to make it work. How do I write a REST API to fetch the data from wordpress in SFCC site?

I have tried hitting a request on this url
https://my-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=content to be searched.
But instead of giving me specific searched content. It gives me all the contents of the site.
Even if I search for other things it shows the same data

Comment: Maybe check search results section ? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/

Comment: This did not help @Snuffy